# windows forms inspector, by click

Tags: .net, winforms, inspector

I am wanting to make an inspector of sorts for a windows app.
so that I can fire it up (from inside the app itself) - it will give me a crosshair maybe and I can click on an item in a form/usercontrol - button, list or some such and it will return me the clicked controls name and maybe the form in which it sits.
so ideally I **wouldn't** have to dynamically add a click to absolutely everything in the form I am viewing, and catch the item from that..

presumably this is possible?
could someone maybe give me a pointer or 2
any help greatly appreciated

thanks

nat

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163617.aspx

Comment: thanks all. ended up ripping bits out of hawkeye, but actually finding it doesn't always get quite the granularity I am after on some specific controls..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you already seen the [Hawkeye](http://hawkeye.codeplex.com/)? This should work for any general application, including Winforms. For WPF there is a special application called [Snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/). Both tools are open source so you can look into their code if you want to implement something on your own.

Answer (score 1):

The nuget package [WinForm.Inspector.Tool](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WinForm.Inspector.Tool/#) is probably the best choice out there right now.